# Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)

Tags: jetbrains-ide, dataspell

When I tried to run the last line of the code block, the IDE returns `Process finished with exit code 133 (interrupted by signal 5: SIGTRAP)`. Any idea?

When I tried to load `library(dplyr)`, it gives me the same error.

[image]

Comment: Getting the same error with R in DataSpell. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In case you installed R through home-brew. This seems to be a known issue. [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/R-1419/Support-R-installed-from-HomeBrew).

I faced the same thing. Using the install from their website resolved the issue.

Comment: Installing an older version of R through home-brew might also work. See youtrack issue.